# OOAD - Properties representing relationships between two types

Tags: relationship, data-modeling, ooad

I have started to model some city-transport data (bus lines and bus stops) for a community project. The data arrived to me as JSON files, and I'd like to create some classes from it, considering the already available data at first.

There is a `BusLine` object, whose JSONs don't contain information about which `BusStop` are related to it.

And there is a large collection of `BusStop`, of which one property is `BusLines`, a collection of (references to) bus lines which pass about that stop.

So far I have modelled this (C# style, but intended just for visualization at first):

```
public class BusLine
{
    public String code;
    public String name;
    public List<DirectPosition> route;
}


public class BusStop
{
    public String code;
    public DirectPosition location;
    public List<BusLine> busLines;
}
```

My doubt, from now, is this: most probably, I'll want to know the `BusStops` associated with a given `BusLine`. I imagine some possible ways of doing it, but am not sure at all how this rather trivial situation should be addressed. My naive thoughts:

1. Create a `getStops()` method that would look somewhere to check which stops existed along that route, and create such list on-the-fly;
2. Create an explicit `List<BusStop> stops` property in `BusLine` class (that sounds very wrong);
3. Eliminate containment altogether and create a third, "Relation" kind of class that would manage (somehow) the relations between those classes. That would mean the knowledge about those relations, extracted from the JSON files, wouldn't be stored "inside" the entities, but somewhere else.

I am pretty sure this is a common pattern (I'd bet there's at least one design pattern for that), but my current level of knowledge gives me no clue...

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Isn't "route" representing list of bus-stops on a BusLine, given that "location" attribute of BusStop identifies it?

Comment: @WandMaker actually `route` is the list of every position along a bus line. Some of them are stops, but most of them are just points along the bus trajectory. While `BusStop` can be geometrically defined by location, the fact that it lies along a bus line doesn't necessary mean that the bus running that line can take passengers at that point (it might be an express or direct bus, for example).